# Why is Type[T] defined to be covariant in T?

Tags: python-3.x, covariance, python-typing

[PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects) declares that `typing.Type[T]` is covariant, i.e. that for any types `A` and `B`, `B` being a subtype of `A` implies that `Type[B]` is a subtype of `Type[A]`, which is obviously wrong:

```
>>> from typing import Type
>>> 
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, x: int): pass
... 
>>> t: Type[object] = A
>>> t()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

What is the rationale behind that decision?

To rule out the error above, every class would need to allow calling `__init__()` with no arguments, which is not enforced at least by `mypy`. Is there any documentation of that exception?